# RelativeLayout height 'wrap_content' does not wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I'm making a layout to replicate a custom dialog. For the bottom portion of my dialog, the `RelativeLayout` hosting the positive, neutral, and negative buttons has an extended height even though I set the `RelativeLayout` height to `wrap_content`.

My layout XML is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dim_dark" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_Message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:text="TextView" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Positive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button_Neutral"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Neutral"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Negative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_Neutral"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        // Assign content references
        TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_Message);
        message.setText("Are you sure you want to sign out?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you mean by "extended height"? I just literally copy-pasted your xml and it seems to render fine. At least I don't see any 'extended height' you might be referring to. Here's a cutout of what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/uL1E9.png

Comment: Right. Eclipse displays it fine. But the actual Nexus One device doesn't. It's really weird...

Comment: Perhaps it's something that happens at runtime? Could you add the code you use to create your custom dialog?

Comment: I have observed if you have something that says `MATCH_PARENT` inside `Relative Layout` with respective parameter set to `WRAP_CONTENT` for `Relative Layout` that also causes problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any problems rendering the layout correctly in Eclipse (as commented earlier), or on a Motorola Defy MB525. However, if I would set the activity's theme to Theme.Dialog, it was showing up squeezed length-wise, resulting in only the neutral button being visible. There are also some simplifications you could do to the layout as presented in your question, e.g. unnecessary nesting of the title TextView and (ab)using a LinearLayout for a horizontal divider.

I changed some small things resulting in the layout below. Perhaps you can give that a try?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_divider3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_Message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Positive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Neutral"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Negative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, in stead of using an activity to emulate a dialog, you could also just use this layout for a 'real' dialog. There's a good [example on creating custom dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) on the Android dev site.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Why was it rendering weirdly? I thought Eclipse's rendering of the UI layout would be consistent to the Android device's.

Comment: To be honest: I'm not sure. I wasn't able to reproduce your problem on my device(s). Potentially it could've been a bad build - did you try cleaning your project in Eclipse and rebuilding it? Otherwise, I suppose you could transform your initial layout step by step to what I posted and try to determine the cause of your problem that way.